# DigitalOcean - suddenly "This site can’t be reached". Logs show [UFW BLOCK]

Tags: laravel, digital-ocean, laravel-forge

Not sure why my site suddenly can't be reached.

It's a DigitalOcean droplet created via Laravel Forge (laravel 5.7.*).

The site was working fine for months and suddenly can't be reached. No deployments in over 3 months.

I'm able to SSH into the DB and onto the server directly.

Reviewing the log files I see a lot of Kernel: [UFW BLOCK] errors, and it looks to be blocking every request.

Ports: 22, 80, 443 are ALLOW and from Anywhere

Thoughts?

Comment: and. Ports - 22, 80, 443 are ALLOW and from Anywhere

Comment: this question has exactly nothing to do with coding, but with server administration. i strongly suggest you read up on linux firewalls, check your firewall settings, or pay someone with more expertise to do so. server fault might be a better place for this question, btw.

Comment: great advice Franz

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to restart nginx and using

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

and

```
nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

I was able to see there was an error in my redirect_rules.conf. Once I cleared out the redirects in laravel forge and restarted nginx, the site was back up. Oddly, these redirect have existed in laravel forge for months without issue.